# How do I get the first match from regexp_match?

Tags: postgresql-13

I'd like to update a column with just the domain part of an email address.

```
update
  users
set
  email_base_domain = regexp_match(email, '(\w+\.\w+)$')
```

However, `regexp_match` returns a `text[]`. If email is `example@foo.com` the above sets email_base_domain to `{foo.com}`. I would like `foo.com`.

How do I get just the first element as `text` from the `text[]` returned by `regexp_match`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a set of parentheses to group what you want to extract. For example:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(email, '(\w+)\.\w+$')
  FROM users
```

will return `{foo}`, while

```
SELECT regexp_matches(email, '\w+\.(\w+)$')
  FROM users
```

will return '{com}'.

Once you have a text array you can use regular array indexing to extract values from the returned text array. For example:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(email, '(\w+)\.\w+$'))[1]
  FROM users
```

returns `'foo'` and

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(email, '\w+\.(\w+)$'))[1]
  FROM users
```

returns `'com'`.

[db<>fiddle with other alternatives here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b32c28efe1265d33389dad3ab20459b5)

Comment: I may not have been clear, I want `foo.com` not `{foo.com}`. I want only the first element from the array returned by regexp_matches.

Comment: Array indexing examples added. db<>fiddle expanded with further examples.

Comment: Oh, wrap the function call in parens. Thanks! That's all I was looking for.